# Recursion in hierarchical tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, hierarchy

I am tying to iterate through a hierarchical tree in javascript to determine how many levels it has. Here is a short snippet of my tree:

```
parent: [
   { id: 1 }
   {
       child1: [
           { id: 2 }
           {
               child2: [
                   { id: 3 }
                   {}
               ]
           }
       ],
       child3: [
           { id: 4 }
           { 
               child4: [
                   { id: 5 }
                   {}
               ],
               child5: [
                   { id: 6 }
                   {
                       child6: [
                           { id: 7 }
                           {}
                       ]
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
]
```

There will be an unknown number of parents and children. There is 1 certainty:

- Each element (e.g. parent) ALWAYS has 2 objects in it's array.
  1st object is always an ID.
  2nd object contains the children it has. This may be empty or populated

My goal is to determine the number of levels that the tree has. For example, there are 4 levels in this example tree (parent = 1, child1 + child3 are on the same level (2), child4 and child5 are on the same level (3) and child6 = 4).

This is my code so far:

```
for (var j in dependencyTree) {
    if (getObjectSize(dependencyTree[j][1]) > 0) {
        levelsArray.push(j + ': ' + recursiveFunction(dependencyTree[j][1], 1));
    }
}


function recursiveFunction(obj, lvls) {
    if (getObjectSize(obj) > 0) {
        for (var i in obj) {
            recursiveFunction(obj[i][1], lvls++);
        }
    }
    return lvls;
}
```

`getObjectSize()` just returns the size of the object. I.e. how many direct children it has. For example, object `parent` will return 2 (`child1` and `child3`).

In the beginning, the top level `parent` children are passed into the function.

I think my problem is that `for` loop (`for (var i in obj)`) because that may grab the first child `parent` has (`child1`) and will eventually return the number of levels that `child1` has even though `child3` has more.

Any help appreciated.

(Have not yet attempted lodash but have been told it offers no recursive help)

**EDIT**

```
{
    "Mobile": [
        {
            "id": 89
        },
        { 
            "Mobile Client": [
                {
                    "id": 100 
                },
                {}
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Service Platform": [
        {
            "id": 90
        },
        {
            "Service Platform": [
                {..."
```

**EDIT (new proposed format)**:

I have talked with my colleague, the new proposed data format is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Mobile",
        "id": 89,
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Mobile Client",
                "id": 100,
                "children": {}
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

This seems like much more workable data and will be implemented tomorrow

Comment: do you have any control over the formatting of the data? It seems like the data is encoded in a strange ways, specifically, some arrays should be objects and object should be arrays.

Comment: @Daniel I was talking with the guy who supplies the data through a REST Call and he says it is possible to manipulate it. How do you think it could be better formatted?

Comment: I would start by using valid JSON. That means that any object you have should be named, otherwise you traverse through the object using an array-like way

Answer (score 1):

Despite the format, this solution iterates over all elements in arrays as well as in objecs and count them.

```js
function count(array) {
    var c = 0;
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        c++;
        if (typeof a === 'object') {
            Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
                if (Array.isArray(a[k])) {
                    c += count(a[k]);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return c;
}

var parent = [{ id: 1 }, { child1: [{ id: 2 }, { child2: [{ id: 3 }, {}, ] }], child3: [{ id: 4 }, { child4: [{ id: 5 }, {}], child5: [{ id: 6 }, { child6: [{ id: 7 }, {}] }] }] }],
    newFormat = [{ "name": "Mobile", "id": 89, "children": [{ "name": "Mobile Client", "id": 100, "children": {} }] }];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(count(parent), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(parent, 0, 4) + '</pre><hr>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(count(newFormat), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newFormat, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

here is some sample code to give you an idea how to traverse the data - the information is visible through console.

```js
var a = [
   { id: 1 },
   {
   child1: [
       { id: 2 },
       {
           child2: [
               { id: 3 },
               {}
           ]
       }
   ],
   child3: [
       { id: 4 },
       { 
           child4: [
               { id: 5 },
               {}
           ],
           child5: [
               { id: 6 },
               {
                   child6: [
                       { id: 7 },
                       {}
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
   }
];

var getNumChildren=function(obj){
  var a = 0;
  if(obj[1]){
for (var key in obj[1]) {
  a++;
  var res = getNumChildren(obj[1][key]);
  console.log(res,a);
  a += res;
}
  }
  return a;
}


console.log(getNumChildren(a));
```

as far as formatting the data goes, this format might make more sense and be easier to understand and use

```
[
  {"id":1,
    "children":[
      {"id":2,"children":[
        {"id":4,"children":[]},
        {"id":5,"children":[]}
      ]},
      {"id":3,"children":[]}
    ]
  }
]
```

---

*edit*

if you update the data format, you can use this code.

```js
var data =[
  {"id":1,
    "children":[
      {"id":2,"children":[
        {"id":4,"children":[]},
        {"id":5,"children":[]}
      ]},
      {"id":3,"children":[]}
    ]
  },
  {"id":6,"children":[]}
]

var getNumChildren=function(ca){
  var n = ca.length;
  ca.map(function(c){n += getNumChildren(c.children);})
  return n
}

document.write("result: " + getNumChildren(data));
```

Comment: The format of the data will be edited. Check my above edit for clarity. Thank you for your help!